# how to debug google cloud function easily?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

How do I debug GCF without deployment?

Is there a way to debug functions faster while having access to GC storage? Much appreciate!

Currently, Im working on trying to use GCF to access GC storage to retrieve ML model and process images. The function will retrieve the image from the same bucket, run the image through the Ml and paste ML model results to a text file with time and image name.

As a beginner coder on GCF, im constantly having to debug and therefore looking for a faster way to debug without waiting for deployment.

Comment: You can't "debug" any program without running it.  And the only way I'm aware of to "run" Google Cloud Functions ... is to deploy them.  Q: Are you using the Google Cloud Debugger: https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs?  Q: What programming language are you using for your functions?

Comment: i debug when i deploy the gcf, not using google cloud debugger (I read somewhere that it doesnt do google cloud function.. will look into it). using python to code out the function, thanks for the prompt response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is simply a piece of code! Run it to test it.

If you want to do that easily and in a similar way as Cloud Functions run it, you can use the [Function Framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework), compliant in many languages.

Personally I prefer to wrap my code in a custom webserver, as I described in one of my first article [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1). And rapidly, I choose to abandon Cloud Functions to Cloud Run, again in a pretty [recent article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/why-i-definitively-switched-from-cloud-functions-to-cloud-run-635d03f1eb4d)

*You could have issues with authentication and stuff like that, let me know if it the case **(and do not generate a service account key file ;) )***